# Postgresql Service Start Fail How I Can Backup My Database - Cenos

Tags: postgresql

I Use Centos 5 and boot from linux rescue
PostgreSQL Fail on start and I need my database on Postgresql How I can backup postgresql database without use service (copy database files and ...)

thanks

Comment: This should go to serverfault

Comment: Did you tried [PG_DUMP](http://www.commandprompt.com/ppbook/x17860)?

Comment: pg_dump: Connection to Database "root" failed: could not connect to server : no such file or directory
us the server running locally and accepting connections on unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.ogsqk.5432"

Comment: then you can try the filesystem backup: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/backup-file.html

Comment: I Havn't this dir: /usr/local/pgsql/data

Answer (score 0):

Copy all your database files (data and config) into a new system, with a new database (same version). That's all.